# I have bad [news] for you

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

**Edit**: All questions have been retagged.

[news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news) has [288 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news), [29 of which are closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bnews%5D%20closed%3Ayes).

The current definition of the news tag says:

> News is the communication of selected information on current events. It is shared in various ways: among individuals and small groups (such as by word of mouth or newsletters); with wider audiences (such as by publishing, either in print or online, or broadcasting, such as on television or radio);

Such overly broad tags are prone to misuse, as shown by almost all existing questions.

### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? And is it unambiguous?

It does not describe the content of the question whatsoever, because it is incredibly ambiguous. News will differ around the world, and what may be news in 1 country, may not be in the country next to it. This tag is also used for questions related to [rss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rss). This tag is also used for places where people use a news grid like layout page.

### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

The tag description is totally off-topic for our site, some of the ambiguous meanings of the tag are on-topic.

### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

This tag only adds information in the form of "keywords", it describes that the author is making something that uses news item/looks like news items.

### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. There are too many meanings in too many contexts to pinpoint one specifically.

---

A close friend of this tag is [rss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rss) with 6574 questions, having [34  questions in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rss%20news?mode=all), this tag is on-topic for Stack Overflow, and should be kept.

Another friend of this tag is [feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feed) with 1525 questions, having [31  questions in common](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news%20feed?mode=all), the feed tag seems to be simulair to the RSS tag, only a little broader.

There are also [61 questions tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news%20php?mode=all) [news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news) [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), but this is common when people use the tag as a keyword.

---

**Please note that burninations are not just tag removals** - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. For more information, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392), or the [unofficial SOCVR process](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md#process).

Comment: Most of the questions seem to be along the lines of "I'm processing a news feed from ..." but there is the occasional [rare question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36344249/18356) that is actually asking about a [library extension called News](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/Index.html). There are about 20 of those, which is probably not enough to require a `typo3-news` tag.

Comment: no [news] is good [news]. No one likes bad [news]. :(

Comment: Breaking [news].

Comment: @shoover Then they should just be untagged with [news], right?

Comment: This should have get burninated ages ago! I was about to post a request too but then found this post.

Comment: I got some bad [news] for you son, I got 99 problems and this tag is one.

Comment: @CaptJak I quite liked [bad \[news\]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bad_News_(band)). Even if they were a spoof.

Comment: With a bit of help from a mod on the lone locked question, this tag is now BURNINATED

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On each question, the [news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news) tag should be replaced with one of these (if news context is relevant to the question):

- [python-newspaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-newspaper) for python `newspaper` module
- [web-scraping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping) for getting content from the websites (e.g. news)
- [rss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rss) or [feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feed) for questions regarding RSS feeds
- [tx-news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tx-news) for questions about TYPO3 News extension
- [facebook-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-feed) or [facebook-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/facebook-api) for questions about Facebook News feed
- [news-feed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/news-feed) for all kinds of questions regarding implementing updates for data (e.g. news)
- [google-news](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-news) for questions regarding Google news
- [notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/notifications) or [updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/updates) for questions regarding updating information or notifying user
- *Edit to add more*

Comment: "newspaper for python newspaper module" no, freaking no. [tag:python-newspaper] if necessary, but tags that has a common real world counterpart are a no go.

Comment: @Braiam I agree with you. But this tag should be created and those 'newspaper' questions should be retagged then.

Comment: Tag creation is no issue, creating a bad tag is.

Comment: In many cases, the tag can simply be removed. For instance, [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38016703/215552) the fact that the OP's database contains news is irrelevant to the question and should not be replaced with any tag.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan yes, you are right